# Webdriver.waitUntil doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

I'm using wedriverio 4.5:

```
./node_modules/.bin/wdio -v
v4.5.2
```

I need to wait until some element exists and if it doesn't exist handle this situation.

for example:

```
let element = browser.element('.unexisting');
browser.waitUntil(
        function () {
            return element.isExisting();
        },
        1000,
        'Element is not found.'
);
```

But if element doesn't exist on the page, webdriver marks my test as failed and shows message: 'Timeout of 10000ms exceeded. Try to reduce the run time or increase your timeout for test specs (http://webdriver.io/guide/testrunner/timeouts.html); if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.'

1. How can I handle this situation?

   - I tried try-catch block, but anyway I see same message about timeout and failed test.
   - I tried element.waitForExist() but behavior is the same
   - I tried to use error handler (but it doesn't help)

   browser.on('error', function(e) {
      console.log ('handle browser error'); 
   })
2. Why don't I see my message 'Element is not found.'?

Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't waitUntil return a promise? Have you tried adding a .catch((error) => {Handle error here})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your waitForXXX command doesn't take longer than your spec timeout. If it does increase your spec timeout, in your case mochaOpts.timeout. See more here http://webdriver.io/guide/testrunner/timeouts.html#Framework-related-timeouts

Comment: Thank your for your reply! But It doesn't work anyway - result the same. I've updated post with correct code. Can you please check?

Comment: just use waitForExist then